# In string how to count recursive word using php

Tags: php, string, function

I am a still beginner for php all thing. I am stuck here .

I want to count word "run" in variable $all.

i am doing it in wrong way.
Please help me with this.

```
$a="run";
$a1="run1";
$a2="run";
$a3="run2";
$a4="run";
$a5="run";
$a6="run";


$all="$a $a1 $a2 $a3 $a4 $a5 $a6";

$count=0;

while(strpos($all,'arun') !== false) 
{
    $count=$count+1;
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Why the javascript tag?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Recurring, not recursive. Kinda an important distinction, though this would be interesting to implement recursively. Also, is checking for the word "arun" a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's inbuilt function:

[substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

It returns number of times a substring (part of a string) is repeated in a string.

Example:

`substr_count ($your_string , $substring);`

It returns count of the number of times the substring is repeated.

Comment: how is this an 'answer'? This is more of a comment. You should elaborate on what the function is, how it is used and even give an example. Linking to another site is *NEVER* an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a="run";
$a1="run1";
$a2="run";
$a3="run2";
$a4="run";
$a5="run";
$a6="run";

$all="$a $a1 $a2 $a3 $a4 $a5 $a6";

$count = substr_count($all, 'run');

echo $count;
```